# Wives of the Shevatim

Tags: marriage, women, conversion-to-judaism, shevatim-12-tribes, canaan

Do any midrashim etc detail the names and background of each the wives of the sons of Jacob?

I know the book of Jubilees does, but that is not considered 'canonical'.

Besides that, I only know of the few mentions we get in the Torah of a couple of the wives and daughters - Judah's Canaanite wife Bat-Shua, then Tamar, and that Joseph married Asenath, who could be either Egyptian or Dinah's daughter by Shechem's rape, depending on interpretation (plus the mention that Asher had a daughter called Serach).

Aish seems to reckon that they generally all married foreign women who converted:
https://aish.com/conversion-in-biblical-times/?gclid=CjwKCAjwjMiiBhA4EiwAZe6jQ0dFkz2tQdIIziYfT_LE-4OGOWyu2EgFw4388cqU9pZg2-5ueEV9SBoCYhQQAvD_BwE

I'm aware that there is also the interpretation that each of the Shevatim was born with an accompanying unmentioned sister, but that points towards all of them marrying their half-sisters, which seems a bit much even for the Torah, especially if we go with the tradition that they all followed the laws (or tried to) even before it was given.

Edit:
Further on this, Shemida seems to be named as a son of Manasseh according to Numbers 26:32, Joshua 17:2, and 1 Chronicles 7:19.
We hear that Manasseh's unnamed wife bears Asriel and that Aramiah/Amoritess concubine bears Machir and that lineage continues to Gilead, but it's then unclear who bore Shemida, Helek, Hepher etc (these all seem to be Manasseh's sons, although I've also seen them described as Gilead's sons).
Any clarification?

Comment: Just note Bat-Shua wasn't her name. Her name isn't given. Her father was Shua and she's referred to as "the daughter of Shua"

Comment: related https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/78862/759

Comment: @DoubleAA Thankyou for the link. I was already aware that 'Bat-Shua' = 'daughter of Shua', it was just quicker to write it that way.

Comment: Ephraim's wife is mentioned in [Chronicles 1:7:23](https://www.sefaria.org.il/I_Chronicles.7.23?vhe=Tanach_with_Ta%27amei_Hamikra&lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en), but nameless.

Comment: Would also be interesting to expand this to other important biblical figures. For example Caleb married Batya, Joshua married Rahab, and Noah married Joan of Ark.

Comment: @Avraham
There seems to be some disagreement about Caleb marrying Batya - 1 Chr 2:19 gives him  Azibah, Jerioth and Ephrath (after Azibah's death) as wives, and some rabbinals sources say that Ephrath = Miriam, but Josephus deems Hur the husband of Miriam. 
https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/132682/miriam-batya-and-azubah

Similarly, the midrash does attest that Rahab married Joshua following her conversion (BT Megillah 14b), but Noah's wife being called Joan (of Arc or otherwise) seems to be a widespread misconception based purely on the pun. Rashi names her as Na'amah.

Comment: I'm relieved you mentioned that about Miriam I was SO sure that was true and then when I saw in the gemara he married Batya I thought I was crazy. Looks like a stirah in the gemara. Re Joan of Arc, yes that was a joke.

Answer (score 3):

The Torah Shleima to Number 26:59 brings an interesting manuscript midrash that says Levi's wife was named Otah, literally "Her." This is based on the apparently ungrammatical structure of the pasuk:

> נט  וְשֵׁם אֵשֶׁת עַמְרָם, יוֹכֶבֶד בַּת-לֵוִי, אֲשֶׁר יָלְדָה אֹתָהּ לְלֵוִי, בְּמִצְרָיִם; וַתֵּלֶד לְעַמְרָם, אֶת-אַהֲרֹן וְאֶת-מֹשֶׁה, וְאֵת, מִרְיָם אֲחֹתָם. *The name of Amram's wife [was] Yocheved bat Levi, who ***her (otah)*** bore to Levi in Egypt. And she bore to Amram Aharon, Moses, and Miriam their sister.*

It would seem the pasuk should have said "hi" (i.e., she) bore rather than "otah" (i.e., her). So the midrash explains that Otah is a proper name, which would make the pasuk grammaical.